# Prove that for vertices $a,b,c$ in a strongly connected digraph, $d(b,c) + d(c,a) + d(a,b) \leq 3|V| - 4$.

Tags: graph-theory

As $G$ is strongly connected, we know that there exists a path in either direction  between any of the vertices $a,b,c$. For a simple graph, a reasonable approach would seem to be to construct a path, say $g = (g_1,g_2, \ldots g_z)$, with $g_1$ as vertex $a$ and the endpoint $g_h$ as vertex b. We then call this the minimum distance path between vertices $a$ and $b$. Then we can further construct a path $t = (t_1, t_2, \ldots t_h)$ such that $t_1$ is vertex $c$ and $t_h = g_i$ is a vertex on the $g$ path and path $t$ is the minimum length path from vertex $c$ to the vertex $g_i$ on the $g$ path.

If $d(a,b) = z$ (that is, the length of our minimum path $g$) and $d(c,g_i) = h$, then as we know if there exists a walk from $a$ to $b$  of length $k$ in a simple graph, then $d(a,b) \leq k$, then it follows $d(c,a) \leq h + i$ and $d(b,c) \leq (z-i) + h$. So we can then combine these inequalities to prove a result for a simple graph, but I am unsure how to extend this sort of construction proof to a digraph. My guess is that there is a result regarding digraphs about what the existence of a walk in a strongly connected digraph implies in terms of a $d(u,v)$, but I do not know what it is.

I am also trying to construct an example for |V| = 5 to visualize when this distance sum equals $3|V| - 4$, but the nearest I can conceive is a directed cycle graph $C_5$ such that $d(b,c)+d(c,a)+d(a,b) = 3|V| - 5$, not quite right.

Comment: Isn't the directed $C_3$ a counterexample? When the graph is $c\rightarrow b\rightarrow a\rightarrow c$, then $d(a,b)=d(b,c)=d(c,a)=2$ and $d(a,b)+d(b,c)+d(c,a)=6> 5=3\cdot |V|-4$.

Comment: Ah yes. I neglected to specify that this proof is for cases with the number of vertices greater than four. Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume $n=|V|>3$. The proof is not hard to find, but a bit annoying to formalize.

A path in $G$ must be of length $\leq n-1$ (because at most $n$ vertices), so the sum of three path lengths is at most $3n-3$. So the only way to violate

$$d(a,b)+d(b,c)+d(c,a)\leq 3n-4$$

is when all involved distances are maximal, i.e. of length $n-1$, hence the corresponding paths pass through *all* vertices. Say the path from $a$ to $b$ is

$$a=v_1\rightarrow v_2\rightarrow\cdots\rightarrow v_n=b.$$

For this path to be the shortest possible path, there cannot be an edge from $v_i$ to $v_j$ for any $i>j+1$ $(*)$. Further, say $c=v_k$:

$$a=v_1\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow c\rightarrow v_{k+1}\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow v_n=b.$$

Now we need even such a path from $b$ to $c$. It must especially pass through all the vertices $v_{k+1},...,v_{n-1}$, befor visiting $a$, because otherwise we would need to violate $(*)$. So, after passing through all these vertices, one of them (say $v_m,k<m<n$) must be connected to $a$ directly (again because of $(*)$, think about it for a while). But now

$$c\rightarrow\cdots\rightarrow v_m\rightarrow a$$

is a path from $c$ to $a$ shorter than $n-1$. This "shorther than $n-1$" is the point where $n>3$ is needed. With some effort you may be abled to show that $d(a,c)=d(c,b)=d(b,a)=\frac{n-1}2$. So there is some work left to be done.

I am sure one can find a more elegant proof of this, especially deriving a much better bound on $d(a,b)+d(b,c)+d(c,a)$ dependent on $n$. I cannot imagine $3|V|-4$ is very tight for bigger $n$ as you noticed by yourself.